# Is $f$ an open map?

Tags: general-topology

Let $f\,\colon (0, +\infty) \to [-1,1]$ be given as $f(x) = \sin(x)$, where $\mathbb R$ is given the usual euclidean metric topology and $(0, +\infty)$ and $[-1,1]$ are given the relative subspace topology. Is $f$ an open map?

Comment: What do you expect, and why?

Comment: I believe it's open but I am unable to give a complete correct proof. @DanielFischer

Comment: Good. Why do you believe it's open?

Comment: Starting with positive values for sin(x) if for every open interval (a,b) in (0,inf) if pi/2 belongs to (a,b) then the image =(min{sin(a), sin(b)} , 1] else if b< pi/2 then sin(x) is an increasing function this implies the image is  (sin(a),sin(b)) and so on considering all cases of positive/negative & increasing/decreasing I get open intervals in [-1,1]. Is the proof correct? @DanielFischer

Comment: It's an incomplete sketch of course, and you must not forget intervals whose image is $[-1,1]$, but if you fill in the details, you get a correct proof.

Comment: yes of course that was only one case. Thank you!! @DanielFischer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the open intervals are a basis for the topology on $(0,\infty)$, it suffices to show that $f$ maps open intervals to open subsets of $[-1,1]$. Let $I = (a,b)$ be an open interval in $(0,\infty)$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f(I)$ is an interval by the intermediate value theorem. Let $c,d$ be the endpoints of $f(I)$. If $f(I)$ contains $c$ or $d$, then $c$ or $d$ is a local extremum of $f$ on $I$. But the only local extremum of $f$ are $\pm 1$. If $f(I)$ is not a single point, then the possible cases are thus

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
f(I) &= (c,d) \\
f(I) &= (c,1] \\
f(I) &= [-1,d) \\
f(I) &= [-1,1], \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

all of which are open in the relatively subspace topology of $[-1,1]$. To see that $f(I)$ is not a single point, just note that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the preimage $f^{-1}(x)$ is either empty or a collection of discrete points, hence no open interval can map to a single point.

Comment: Don't you also need to exclude the cases `[1, 1]` and `[-1, -1]`, for completeness? (Not that that's hard to do, but it may be worth mentioning.)

Comment: Ah, good point.

Answer (score -1):

It's not so hard to proof that the image of every open interval is an open set in the subspace the topology, since the image of an open interval can be one of the following 4. $(a,b), [-1,a), (a,1], [-1, 1]$.

Comment: This is not an answer tbh. Maybe you want to leave this as a comment.

Comment: This is not a proof, it is obvious, but I think, it is more than a hint.